# php cURL how to process all the request on the page

Tags: php, curl

when I make a GET request with curl to a remote web server I own in the access log I only see one request (the initial one) if I visit with a real browser I get the initial request plus all the other GET requests like css, images, js etc..

Is there a way for cURL to actually act like a browser and process all the page?
Isn't it supposed to do this? Otherwise what is the response output, the html code only?

Comment: a single request to the page does not request the images and css. I'm not sure if php curl has something built in for this, but one thing you can do is store the source code, and parse it out for all the resources, and curl those urls as well.

Comment: Your page (the content you're trying to get) isn't rendered by a user-agent. So no external files will be loaded but the ones you request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most command line browsers would ignore the additional requests as well...

cURL does not render any markup and has no need for the other data.  What good are images and styling definitions in a text only view?

You can simulate these requests by parsing the markup returned by the initial request and following on with the other requests as a browser would.